# Controlling the legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have composed code that plots the density plots for a certain numeric variable for two Classes using ggplot.  But I can not handle the legend appearance. My code is the following:

```
mu <- ddply(german, "Class", summarise, grp.mean=mean(Credit_amount))


ggplot(german, aes(x=Credit_amount, fill=as.factor(Class))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.3)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.6)+
  geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color= as.factor(Class)),
             size = 2, alpha = 0.6)+
  labs(title="Credit_amount for the Two Classes (Good and Bad Creditors",x="Credit_amount", y = "Density") +
scale_fill_manual(limits=c("1", "0"), labels = c("Bad Creditors", "Good Creditors"), values = c("blue", "red"))
+ labs(fill="Class of Customers")
```

The plot is the following. I have annotated the changes I am aiming for:
[image]

What I am doing wrong?  What should I do instead?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone down-voted you probably because it is impossible to reproduce what you have done without the data set "german". You should try to translate your question to use a data set that everyone has access to.

This is roughly what you have, except using the data set mtcars:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl = paste0(mtcars$cyl, ' cyl')
mu <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, grp.mean=mean(mpg))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, fill=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.3)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.6)+
  geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color= as.factor(cyl)),
             size = 2, alpha = 0.6)+
  labs(title="Title",x="mpg", y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_manual(limits=c('4 cyl', '6 cyl', '8 cyl'), 
                    labels = c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", '8 cyl'), 
                    values = c("red", "green", 'blue')) + 
  labs(fill="Class of Customers")
```

[image]

To change the order of the categories in the legend, include a line of code like this, which sets the levels for the factor cyl to be in the desired order:

```
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = c('8 cyl', '6 cyl', '4 cyl'))
mu <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, grp.mean=mean(mpg))
```

Then in the ggplot code, remove references to as.factor(cyl), and simply put cyl, since cyl is already a factor.  Also, add the line +guides(color=FALSE) at the end to remove the unwanted legend:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, fill=cyl)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position="identity", alpha=0.3)+
  geom_density(alpha=0.6)+
  geom_vline(data=mu, aes(xintercept=grp.mean, color= cyl),
             size = 2, alpha = 0.6 )+
  labs(title="mtcars example",x="mpg", y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_manual(limits=c('8 cyl', '6 cyl', '4 cyl'), 
                    labels = c("8 cyl", "6 cyl", '4 cyl'), 
                    values = c("red", "green", 'blue')) + 
  labs(fill="Class of Customers")+
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]